# Using $\frac{{{{\sin }^4}x}}{2} + \frac{{{{\cos }^4}x}}{3} = \frac{1}{5}$ finding the value of $\frac{{{{\sin }^8}x}}{8} + \frac{{{{\cos }^8}x}}{27}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

If $\frac{{{{\sin }^4}x}}{2} + \frac{{{{\cos }^4}x}}{3} = \frac{1}{5}$, then

(A)${\tan ^2}x = \frac{2}{3}$

(B)$\frac{{{{\sin }^8}x}}{8} + \frac{{{{\cos }^8}x}}{27} = \frac{1}{125}$

(C)${\tan ^2}x = \frac{1}{3}$

(D) $\frac{{{{\sin }^8}x}}{8} + \frac{{{{\cos }^8}x}}{27} = \frac{2}{125}$

The official answer is A and B.

My approach is as follow

$\frac{{{{\sin }^4}x}}{2} + \frac{{{{\cos }^4}x}}{3} = \frac{1}{5} \Rightarrow \frac{{{{\sin }^4}x}}{2} + \frac{{{{\left( {1 - {{\sin }^2}x} \right)}^2}}}{3} = \frac{1}{5}$

$ \Rightarrow \frac{{{{\sin }^4}x}}{2} + \frac{{1 + {{\sin }^4}x - 2{{\sin }^2}x}}{3} = \frac{1}{5} \Rightarrow 3{\sin ^4}x + 2 + 2{\sin ^4}x - 4{\sin ^2}x = \frac{6}{5}$

$ \Rightarrow 2 + 5{\sin ^4}x - 4{\sin ^2}x = \frac{6}{5} \Rightarrow 10 + 25{\sin ^4}x - 20{\sin ^2}x = 6 \Rightarrow 25{\sin ^4}x - 20{\sin ^2}x + 4 = 0 \Rightarrow {\left( {5{{\sin }^2}x - 2} \right)^2} = 0 \Rightarrow {\sin ^2}x = \frac{2}{5}$

${\cos ^2}x = \frac{3}{5}$, Hence ${\tan ^2}x = \frac{2}{3}$,

which is correct as per the official answer

$\frac{{{{\sin }^2}x}}{2} = \frac{1}{5}\& \frac{{{{\cos }^2}x}}{3} = \frac{1}{5}$

cubing and adding we get

$\frac{{{{\sin }^8}x}}{8} + \frac{{{{\cos }^8}x}}{{27}} = \frac{2}{{125}}$ but it is **wrong** as per the official answer key and the correcct answer is $\frac{{{{\sin }^8}x}}{8} + \frac{{{{\cos }^8}x}}{27} = \frac{1}{125}$

Where I am making mistake.

Comment: Your mistake is that 

$$\Big( \sin^2(x) \Big)^3 = \sin^{2 \cdot 3}(x) = \sin^6(x)$$

as opposed to $\sin^{2^3}(x) = \sin^8(x)$. Similar for cosine.

Comment: basic property 2 is not squarred but multiplies

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "basic proper 2".

Comment: I mean to say that I made mistake in the basic property $.(a^b)^c=a^{b.c}$

Comment: I was using $(a^b)^c=a^{b^c}$ which is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all ${(a^b)}^c=a^{b^c}$ is wrong .No such identity exists(try $a=2,b=3,c=4$).Hence you would have to take the 4th power on both sides and then adding which will give you result

Now that i have answered your query i present an easier solution.

By Cauchy schwarz inequality $$\frac{\sin^4 x}{2}+\frac{\cos^4x}{3}\ge \frac{{(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)}^2}{5}=\frac{1}{5}$$ For equality we must heve $$\frac{\sin^4 x}{4}=\frac{\cos^4 x}{9} \iff \tan^2 x=\frac{2}{3}$$ Ther rest can be done by your way